# tinyMCE media embed, with media plugin in PHP + MySql

Tags: php, mysql, tinymce

i'm using tinyMCE and i can't find the answer for this in their forums.

I'm using the "media" plugin to embed flash. the html result in html preview is normal:

```
<p><iframe src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/lWRi7gDYjVY" frameborder="0" width="425" height="350"></iframe></p>
```

the result saved to the database is quite different though, using mysql_real_escape_string it saves:

```
<p><img data-mce-json="{'type':'iframe','video':{'sources':[]},'params':{'src':'http://www.youtube.com/embed/lWRi7gDYjVY','frameborder':'0'},'width':'425','height':'350'}" class="mceItemMedia mceItemIframe" src="http://localhost/assets/scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/trans.gif" data-mce-src="assets/scripts/tiny_mce/themes/advanced/img/trans.gif" width="425" height="350"></p>
```

and that is what is rendered on my page's html, showing only a white space the size of the iframe...

I'm really stuck and i don't know what to do. 
Thanks

/*Update*/

well, i found out the source of the problem: i am saving my contents through AJAX; i haven´t found a way to get the HTML content out of the editor with javascript so i was hacking it with a jQuery selector:

```
$('div').find('iframe').contents().find('body').html()
```

so that way i get the "wrong html" and it only happened with youtube videos so far.

My question is: how can i obtain the editor's HTML so i can post it through AJAX?

Thank you once again.

Comment: please post your tinymce init and tell us which tinymce version you use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To obtain the editor's HTML use the following

```
// this is "content" by default else it is the id of your 
// html element you get the editor for (usually a textarea)
var editor_id = 'put_your_editor_id_here';
editor = tinymce.get(editor_id);
var content = editor.getContent();
```

You may have a closer look at the [tinymce API.](http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/wiki.php/API3%3amethod.tinymce.Editor.getContent)

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 0):

This is because the media plugin strips the tags that are considered invalid.

Can you try to change the option Valid_elements in Init and assign to *[*].

Try it.

good luck